# Does Google provide any API to comment on user reviews

Tags: google-maps, google-plus, google-places-api

I am the owner of a business page and I want to know that does Google provide any API to comment on the reviews of my Page.
Right now, I am getting all the reviews through Google Place API but, didn't get the API to comment on individual user reviews.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's a brilliant idea. My belief is that they do not yet support this feature. I would contact the Google Maps API for Business sales team [here](http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/request.py?&utm_campaign=http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/request.py?&utm_campaign=placesapiblog&contact_type=gme).

According to [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/business/0tZTDXHuh00), you can respond to reviews using google's interface, but your responses may disappear if they're not content relevant.

Loading in reviews requires an additional license... http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/

Google Places Enterprise API:

> Places API Enterprise Customers
>
> Some features of the Places API — **such as review summaries**, and
>   certain request filters — requires additional licensing, available as
>   part of a Places API enterprise license.
>
> You can verify that your account has been enabled for Places API
>   enterprise features as follows:
>
> Visit the APIs Console and log in with your Google Account. Select the
>   project that was created for you when you signed up. The project name
>   will start with Google Maps APIs for Business. Click the Services link
>   from the left-hand menu. The Places API - Zagat Content service should
>   be enabled. Note that only the initial owner of the project will be
>   able to see the Places API - Zagat Content service. The Places API
>   service should be disabled.

source: [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?hl=en)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the last paragraph and my API console is configured properly for that. I tried various thing but didnt get any success to implement the 'Respond to Review Part'